# How do I check a git config value in a Bash if/else statement?

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to read a git config value in a bash script, and conditionally act on it depending on whether it's `true` or `false`.

I'd expect to be able to do:

```sh
if [ $(git config --get myvalue) ]; then
   echo "True"
else
   echo "False"
fi
```

However, when I run the above example, `True` is *always* printed. Directly comparing the value to `true` seems to work properly, like so:

```sh
if [ $(git config --get myvalue) = true ]; then
   echo "True"
else
   echo "False"
fi
```

However, most programming languages don't require a direct comparison to a boolean value, so this goes against what I'd expect.

It does actually seem like this works:

```sh
if $(git config --get myvalue); then
   echo "True"
else
   echo "False"
fi
```

My understanding is that putting an expression in `[ ]` calls the `test` command under the hood. However, it's not obvious to me why the boolean expression isn't evaluated properly with `test`.

Why doesn't `[ ]` evaluate the expression correctly?

Comment: Use `get config --type bool --get myvalue` to ensure that you actually get a result of `true` or `false`, rather than a possible synonym.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash doesn't have boolean variables. `true` is a string and could be written as `"true"` or `'true'` with no change in semantics. It is normal and correct to explicitly compare it to `true` or `false`.

```
if [[ $(git config --get myvalue) == true ]]; then
   echo "True"
else
   echo "False"
fi
```

---

> ```
> if $(git config --get myvalue); then
>    echo "True"
> else
>    echo "False"
> fi
> ```

Don't do this. It's a major security vulnerability. What it's really is doing executing whatever command `git config` outputs. It happens to work because there are commands named `true` and `false` which succeed and fail, respectively.

What if that command weren't `true` or `false`? What if somebody were to change `myvalue` to `rm -rf /`? You'd be having a bad time...

Comment: Also, `--type bool` should be passed to ensure that you get back `true`, rather than possibly `yes` (which would trigger a false negative for the suggested code and an infinite loop leading to memory exhaustion for the second).